# How to Link custom week numbers with an existing time tree graph up to minutes in Neo4J?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I already have a graph (time tree) that contains Year, Month, Day, Hour and Minutes. It is something like that of what Mark Needham shows in his [blog link](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/04/19/neo4j-cypher-creating-a-time-tree-down-to-the-day/) but it goes until Minutes instead of days. So the link looks something like this :

```
2017-[:HAS_MONTH]-2-[:HAS_DAY]-25-[:HAS_HOUR]-16-[:HAS_MINUTE]-45
```

I also have Year to week number relation. The starting and ending dates of the Workweek are custom. For eg my week 2 in 2017 starts from 2017-01-05 19:00 (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm) and ends on 2017-01-12 18:59. I have all the nodes between those 2 dates in my time tree but I am not able link them to week 2 node. Is there a way to do this? I am not using graphaware. I managed to do something for this one week by collecting all the days from 5th to 12th and then removing the hours 0 to 18 from 5th and 20th to 23rd on 12. But I need to do this for a couple of years and this method may be very cumbersome. Is there a better way for this?

Comment: you can preprocess the data to include weeks already precalculated in pandas or something similar, to avoid cumbersomeness

Comment: @TomažBratanič : I actually created the time tree also in the Graph. I was hoping I can have this framework and then I have other state data that I can just link with this time tree. It will make the traversal easier for me in the long run.

Comment: what I meant was that you preprocess the weeks in the csv or wherever you have it stored and then import to graph (neo4j)... traversals will be ok once imported into graph, you just preprocess dates to weeks with some scripting language and then import them to graph

Comment: @TomažBratanič Yeah that was my last choice. I am working on getting that done now. Hopefully someone does have an APOC for this :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use apoc [plugin](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures) already :)

`apoc.date.format` uses JAVA simpledateformat under the hood I think. Looking at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html this is already possible. But you have to first parse it into unix and then back.

```
with "2017-01-05 19:00" as date
with apoc.date.parse(date,"s","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") as unix
return apoc.date.format(unix,"s","yyyy ww")
```

Comment: I was using epochtimes on my nodes and actually managed to use this to do the links in a way eventually from cypher